# Newline in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

Can anybody tell me how to save newline in database and also retrieve it in a same manner using asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try \r\n or \n

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server does no processing at all to data sent in. If you send this

```
aaa
bbb

ccc
```

Then this is exactly what is stored, complete with characters 13 and 10

If you are having problems, then it's likely chars 13 and 10 do not get into SQL Server *or* the page is removing them because they are suppressed whitespace in HTML.

To summarise, the problem is almost certain **not** to be with SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.Environment.NewLine in .Net to save the newline. If you simply press enter I think SQL saves it as \r\n.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use FormView to submit to a database?

http://sfvt.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/asp-net-tutorial-formview-insert-to-database/